# configuration change in list view

Tags: android, listview, configuration

I've a list view, which has the following:

TextView Edit button Delete button and navigate button.

When user clicks Edit button, I'm loading an Edit Text, Save button and cancel button using ViewSwitcher. I've also used android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" so that the view gets resized when the keyboard gets visible.

The problem here is, when the user clicks on the edit text, the keyboard will appear but the view gets reloaded and the text view will appear.

Also, when the user scrolls the list view into the middle of the page and changes the orientation, list view will load into the start.

I've tried using android:configChange with no result. How to handle this situation using savedInstance Or is there any other way to solve this problem??